# Why am i getting HTTP 404 & sub_code":"S00004 ? IBM Watson

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson

I am using curl command :

> curl -X POST --user "apikey:xxx" \
>   --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   --header "Accept: application/json" \
>   --data-binary @profile.json \
>   "https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api"

and IBM is giving me response:

x{"code":404,"sub_code":"S00004","error":"Not Found"}%

anyone has idea why?

this is my .json file

https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/personality-insights/profile.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST --user "apikey:xxxxxxxx" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --data-binary @profile.json "https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true"
```

Replace `xxxxxxxx` with your apikey. Please avoid using real `apikey` in public in the future. Anyone can use your key. I have edited the question to hide it.
Please follow the [API reference for Personality Insights](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v3/curl.html?curl#methods-api) for more info.

Comment: So the problem was i was using " \ " while i shouldnt ?

Comment: The URL was not complete. You were using `https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api` instead of `https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true`